# Backend communication in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, web-services, http, tcp, communication

I'm interested in finding out people's experiences and preferences for communication with backend servers from Siverlight client apps, specifically the use of web services (ASM, WCF or other) over http.

Do people use the clientside proxy classes you can generate in VS.Net or do you roll your own and use the WebClient & HttpWebRequest classes.

Comment: this is probably more apt for programming.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can see uses in both forums, not only a theoretical question but looking for particular pitfalls people have come across

Answer (score 0):

We've built our product in Silverlight and use OpenRasta on the server to produce REST resources that can be consumed by our Silverlight client. All payloads are JSON and we've written a little wrapper around HttpWebRequest to do all our get/post requests. Simple but very very effective.

And a tip, avoid WCF, far too much complexity and abstraction away from HTTP. It may seem easy to start with using generated proxies etc, but the minute you want more control or something goes wrong you're in black box hell.

HTH

Comment: Andy, I've gone down this route as well for pretty much the same reasons, the fact SL4 only support basic bindings is a major issue. The use of reactive extensions makes interface for the wrapped HttpWebRequest very easy to use.